# Как заставить форму перерисовать картинку?

Tags: spring, mvc, java, jsp

У меня вот такая форма:

```
        <form id="photoUpload" action="<c:url value="/profile     /uploadPhotoFromFile"/>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
          <div style="margin-top: 100px;" align="center">
           <p>
             <img src="<c:url value="/profile/showPhoto"/>" height="250" width="190" alt=""/>

           </p>
           <br>
               <br>
               <a class="submitButton" style="position: relative; overflow: hidden;">
               <spring:message code="label.select" />
               <input type="file" class="file_upload" name="photo" style="position:   absolute; right: 0px; top: 0px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; cursor: pointer; opacity: 0;" id="fileName" onchange="">
               </a>
                <button style="margin-left: 10px" class="submitButton"><spring:message code="label.show" /></button>
               <br>
           </form>
```

Вот методы в контроллере:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/profile/uploadPhoto", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getPhotoForm(Model model, @ModelAttribute("userPhoto") UserPhoto photo) {
    User user = UserContext.getCurrentUser();
    UserPhoto userPhoto = new UserPhoto();
    userPhoto.setPhoto(user.getPhoto());
    model.addAttribute("userPhoto", userPhoto);
    return UPLOAD_PHOTO_VIEW;
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/profile/uploadPhoto", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String submitPhoto(@ModelAttribute("userPhoto") @Valid UserPhoto photo, BindingResult result, HttpServletRequest request, Model model) {
    User user = UserContext.getCurrentUser();
    UserPhoto userPhoto = new UserPhoto();
    userPhoto.setPhoto(user.getPhoto());
    model.addAttribute("userPhoto", userPhoto);
    return UPLOAD_PHOTO_VIEW;
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/profile/showPhoto", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServiceException {

    String offset = request.getParameter("offset");
    response.setDateHeader("Expires", System.currentTimeMillis() + 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
    try {
        response.setContentType("image/jpeg");
        OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
        User user = UserContext.getCurrentUser();
        try {
            response.setContentLength(user.getPhoto().length);
            out.write(user.getPhoto());
        } finally {
            out.close();
        }
        return null;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new ServiceException(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Почему-то по нажатию на кнопку "show" катринка не перерисовывается. Метод "showPhoto" не вызывается.
И как сделать перерисовку сразу после выбора файла (который выбирается при нажатии кнопки с type="file") автоматически без нажатия кнопки "show"?

Comment: @Helena2977, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

1) Тут проблема в том, что браузер кэширует картинку, я в свое время пытался решить ее с помощью правильных заголовков, но, увы, у меня ничего не вышло, самое простое и действующее решение - это сделать конструкцию типа

```
<c:set var="currentTime" value="<%=System.currentTimeMillis()%>"/>
<c:url value="/profile/showPhoto?${currentTime}"/>
```

2) Не уверен, что везде сработает, но попробуйте так: нужно воспользоваться событием onchange, которое у вас уже в коде есть, самый примитивный код будет выглядеть как-то так:

```
<input type="file" class="file_upload" name="photo" onchange="document.getElementsByClassName('submitButton')[0].click()">
```

Comment: Спасибо, получилось с перерисовкой. А как насчет второго вопроса, чтобы картинка как-то перерисовалась сразу послу выбора файла без нажатия на специальную кнопку?

Comment: Внимательно прочитайте мой ответ, пункт 2 это и есть ответ на ваш 2-й вопрос;)